# Python: How to fix an error of VCRUNTIME140.dll

Tags: python, pyqt5, cx-freeze

I create a desktop application with python and in terms of codes it works fine. Then I use the CX_Freeze to get an exectuable file to work with it in any PC without installing anything and also it works but only on my PC.
I want show you my setup.py file:

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
import sys
base = None
if sys.platform == "win32":
    base = "Win32GUI"
executables = [Executable("general.py", base=base)]#, icon='accept.ico')]
#Renseignez ici la liste complète des packages utilisés par votre application
packages = ["idna", "__future__", "PyQt5","sys", "numpy", "cv2", "pyzbar", "validate_email", "urllib.request", "mysql.connector", "datetime", "face_recognition"]
options = {
    'build_exe': {
        'packages':packages,
        'include_files':['icones','TEACH_images']


    },
}

setup(
    name = "bis",
    options = options,
    version = "1.0",
    description = 'Voici mon programme',
    executables = executables
)
```

I execute the command in terminal: python setup.py build. Like I say everything is working on my PC but I get the error in other PC: **impossible d'executer le code car VCRUNTIME140.dll est introuvable**
So how to fix the error or should I use other method or I have to change something in my setup file

Comment: Your users need to install the "Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable Update 3", https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=52685 .  Also make sure you're not building on a 64-bit system and running on a 32-bit system.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VCRUNTIME140.DLL is not getting added when using cx\_freeze in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60603108/vcruntime140-dll-is-not-getting-added-when-using-cx-freeze-in-python)

Comment: It works thank you. But now I get an error of the connexion to the Database:
**mysql.connector.errors.InterfaceError: 2003: can't connect to MySQL server on localhost: 3306(10061 Aucune connexion n'a pu établie car l'ordinateur cible l'a expressément refusée)**

Answer (score 0):

```
options = {
    'build_exe': {
        'packages':packages,
        'include_files':['icones','TEACH_images'],
         "include_msvcr": True


    },
```

Your options parts should be like this.